# Get back variable value from another swift file

Tags: ios, swift, variables

First of all, sorry for the title not very precise.

So, i have a file data.swift with some informations

```
import Foundation

class Data {
    class Entry {
        let filename : String
        let heading : String
        let referenceville: String
        init(fname : String, heading : String, referenceville : String) {
            self.heading = heading
            self.filename = fname
            self.referenceville = referenceville
        }
    }

    var places = [
        Entry(fname: "bordeaux.jpg", heading: "Heading 1", referenceville : "bordeaux"),
        Entry(fname: "lyon.jpg", heading: "Heading 2", referenceville : "lyon")

    ]



    var bordeaux = [
        Entry(fname: "lemarais.jpg", heading: "LE MARAIS", referenceville : "lemarais"),
        Entry(fname: "montmartre.jpg", heading: "MONTMARTRE", referenceville : "montmartre"),
        Entry(fname: "perelachaise.jpg", heading: "PERE LACHAISE", referenceville : "perelachaise"),

    ]

}
```

In another viewcontroller, i m trying to get back a value from above with this :

```
var passedValue:String!  // passedValue coming from a segue from a previous VC
// passedValue could be "places", "bordeaux", ...
     let entry = data.passedValue[indexPath.row]
```

But it's not working message error told me "data doesn't have a member named "passedValue"

How could i set properly the variable ?

Comment: have you try to use construc instead?

Comment: i prefer class , how could i perform that so ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 let entry = Data().places[indexPath.row]
```

To access variables in another class, you need to instantiate it first with `()`

Comment: Guess the name of the variable is "variable", i enter                                   let entry = Data().variable[indexPath.row]  ? Seems doesn't work

Comment: i can already access without (), in this case, the problem is , i don't want a fixed value (places in this example) i want a variable .

Comment: Instead of the `let` keyword, you must use `var`. Then you can modify the property.

Comment: done, and i have written let entry = data.passedValue[indexPath.row],   passedValue is the name of my variable. And it's not working

Comment: here is the error message : data doesn't have a member named "passedValue"